# How to use a requires clause with lambda functor arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++-concepts

Is there any way to apply a general requires clause to the arguments of a lambda functor?

Suppose I have two constraints `C1` and `C2` that I want checked against an argument. I would have expected the following to work since a similar syntax is allowed for functions:

```
[](auto x) requires C1<decltype(x)> && C2<decltype(x)> {
    // ...
}
```

But this [won't compile](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jRlFHgccHmHPyBeW) with GCC 6

Comment: Why don't you just write a normal functor?

Comment: The Concepts TS does not modify the grammar for lambdas, so I think it is not possible to append a requires-clause to a lambda. By altering the definition of *simple-type-specifier*, it allows to use constrained-type-specifiers as parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my humble opinion and based on [Concepts TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0121r0.pdf) *§5.1.4/c4 Requires expressions [expr.prim.req]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> **A requires-expression shall appear only within a concept definition (7.1.7), or within the requires-clause of a template-declaration
>   (Clause 14) or function declaration (8.3.5).**

The above quote specifically dictates the contexts where a `requires` clause can appear and lambdas is not one of them.

Concequently,

```
[](auto x) requires C1<decltype(x)> && C2<decltype(x)> {
    // ...
}
```

Is not valid.

However, in *§5.1.2 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]* there's the following example:

```
template<typename T> concept bool C = true;
auto gl = [](C& a, C* b) { a = *b; }; // OK: denotes a generic lambda
```

So I guess, you could accomplish what you want in the following manner:

```
template <class T> concept bool C1 = true;                                        
template <class T> concept bool C2 = true;
template <class T> concept bool C3 = C1<T> && C2<T>; // Define a concept that combines 
                                                     // `C1` and `C2` requirements.                   

int main() {                                                                      
  auto f = [](C3 x)  { /* Do what ever */ }; // OK generic lambda that requires input 
                                             // argument satisfy `C1` and `C2`                                                                                                                          
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MOF6tAej0eQp95Op)

Comment: Yes, looks like that's true. I found this thread on the concepts group that addresses the same [question](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/concepts/4WraUOsevH8). It's unfortunate as there are lots of cases where the concise concepts syntax isn't sufficient to express the constraint needed. Hopefully, this will be addressed in a future draft.

Comment: Right - I'm aware of the concise concepts syntax. Still it's IMO a defect that you would have to define a completely new concept if you have a more complicated requires clause. Furthermore, that syntax won't work if you have a concept that needs to reference multiple arguments.

Comment: @rnickb based on the link you posted it's not on Adrew Shutton's priorities list  "Making lambdas bigger was not high on our list of priorities (lambdas are supposed to make code shorter).". I kinda agree with it. Lambdas are indeed supposed to make code shorter. On the other hand what you're saying is true, composition of concepts to accomplish what you want, kinda obfuscates the code-base. I guess we'll see in the future what happens :).

Comment: `requires C1<decltype(x)> && C2<decltype(x)> ` is a *requires-clause*, not a *requires-expression*.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question can appear as the first result of some searches¹, it is worth pointing out that adding constraints to the `operator()` of the closure type with `requires` [is possible as of C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

---

¹ At least by typing “c++ lambda function requires” to Google